# Polymorphic mapping type

Tags: python, dictionary, polymorphism, mapping

Is there a polymorphic dict-like type in Python? Here is what I mean by polymorphic: consider a basic class hierarchy with an `Animal` base class and a some derived classes, `Cat`, `Snake`, etc. and let's have our mystery mapping type `mystery_dict`

```
mapping = mystery_dict({
    Animal : 'foo',
    Cat    : 'bar',
    Snake  : 'baz',
    Python : 'eggs',
    Boa    : 'spam'
})
```

Now, I want to have the following lines to be true:

```
mapping[Animal]   == 'foo'
mapping[Cat]      == 'bar'
mapping[Dog]      == 'foo' # No Dog in mapping, take the base class Animal
mapping[Snake]    == 'baz'
mapping[Boa]      == 'spam'
mapping[Anaconda] == 'baz' # No Anaconda in mapping, take the base class Snake
```

I know that I could use a bunch of `isinstance` or an "overload set" with `functools.singledispatch` since Python 3.4 but in some cases, a polymorphic dictionary type would be handy to reduce boilerplate. Does such a type exist in the wild or do I have to create one? Of course, if you have an even better alternative, I would be glad to hear about it.

*Note:* just in case the question gets asked, I have rather simple needs so it doesn't have to handle multiple inheritance.

Comment: Are you writing a new Zope?

Comment: You can 'play' with `pickle` and pass pickled strings as indexes and use `pickle.loads(string)` then.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? `zope.component`/`zope.interface` has multiadapters, can actually do something like this and even more...

Comment: So, why are you not storing this info on the classes themselves then? `Animal.mapping = 'foo'` is inherited by all subclasses.

Comment: But an `Animal` is not a `Dog`, and a `Snake` is not an `Anaconda`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I create a translator from a type-based system to a data-based one and do not have control over any of them.

Comment: @PeterWood I'm only following the single dispatch logic: if you have an exact match, take it, otherwise try to make the most derived parent match, then its parent, etc... Well, polymorphism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is trivial enough to write yourself:

```
from collections.abc import MutableMapping


class PolymorphicDict(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._mapping = dict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for cls in key.__mro__:
            if cls in self._mapping:
                return self._mapping[cls]
        raise KeyError(key)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._mapping[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._mapping[key] = value

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._mapping)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._mapping)
```

This uses the [`class.__mro__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__mro__) to list the class hierarchy of the current object, in method lookup order (Method Resolution Order). This sequence includes the current class and lists all classes all the way up to `object`.

Demo:

```
>>> class Animal: pass
... 
>>> class Cat(Animal): pass
... 
>>> class Dog(Animal): pass
... 
>>> class Snake(Animal): pass
... 
>>> class Python(Snake): pass
... 
>>> class Boa(Snake): pass
... 
>>> class Anaconda(Snake): pass
... 
>>> Anaconda.__mro__
(<class '__main__.Anaconda'>, <class '__main__.Snake'>, <class '__main__.Animal'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> mapping = PolymorphicDict({
...     Animal : 'foo',
...     Cat    : 'bar',
...     Snake  : 'baz',
...     Python : 'eggs',
...     Boa    : 'spam'
... })
>>> mapping[Animal]
'foo'
>>> mapping[Cat]
'bar'
>>> mapping[Dog]
'foo'
>>> mapping[Snake]
'baz'
>>> mapping[Boa]
'spam'
>>> mapping[Anaconda]
'baz'
```

You probably want to look at [`zope.component`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.component) however; this lets you do *exactly this* with added interfaces. It has optimised the lookup mapping to a very high degree to scale the principle to far larger registries of object mappings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's pretty neat :) I will have a look at `zope.component`, the architecture looks interesting.

Comment: @Morwenn: be careful with interfaces there; it can take a moment before you realise that there is a big distinction between classes and interfaces (classes implement, instances provide the interface). If you are using `zope.component` to map *classes* than you want to use `directlyProvides` semantics.